# Configure variable callback URI in Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, okta

I'm trying to configure a new Okta application with a callback URL that will depend on the tenant's subdomain. Meaning I need the same Okta app to accept redirection (using the `redirect_uri` parameter) to `https://0001.my.domain.com/oauth2/callback`, `https://0002.my.domain.com/oauth2/callback` and so on. Notice the `0001` and `0002` subdomains. This may seem strange, but it's for demo purposes. The point is to avoid having to set up a different Okta app per tenant.

Okta's own [docs on the subject](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/submit-app/-/submission2-specific/#protocol-specific-settings) read:

> **Does your Initiate Login URI vary by tenant?** — If **Yes**, enter which part of the Initiate Login URI is customizable. For example, the `subdomain` in `https://<subdomain>.example.com/signin/`.

[image]

However, when I try to do this I run into an error complaining that:

> The redirect URIs must be absolute URIs.

[image]

Maybe I'm just reading this wrong, but I take it to mean that variables/placeholders are supported.

I've searched the rest of the Okta docs but found no additional information on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Okta let you do this, it would not be OAuth 2.0 compliant.

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-16#section-2.1:

> When comparing client redirect URIs against pre-registered URIs, authorization servers MUST utilize exact string matching except for port numbers in "localhost" redirection URIs of native apps.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I misinterpreted their docs then. Thank you for the pointer.